How does the pvarfeols function from the R panelvar package handle fixed effects?
I have been using the pvarfeols function (Fixed Effects Estimator for PVAR Model) from the R panelvar package. It seems like the pvargmm function is a primary feature of the panelvar package but I opted not to use it due to the relatively large size of the data.
My panel data, which is unbalanced, consists of 3 columns (excluding id and time) with approximately 7.6 million observations.
I want to conduct a panel vector autoregression (VAR) analysis on three variables with five lags, incorporating the following controls: firm fixed effects, day fixed effects, and time (clock time) fixed effects.
In the package documentation for the pvarfeols function, I noticed that the 'demean' option is available for transformation. For example:
pvarfeols(
  dependent_vars,
  lags,
  exog_vars,
  transformation = c("demean"),
  data,
  panel_identifier = c(1, 2)
)

However, I am curious about how the 'demean' option is defined in the function.
Does this option subtract a time-series average from each data point to control for firm fixed effects? Or does it also subtract a cross-sectional average from each data point?
Using ChatGPT, I discovered that there might be more options than just 'demean'.
For instance, ChatGPT suggested that 'time-demean' is also available although I am not sure if this is truly the case. When I used the 'time-demean' option, the results of the pvarfeols function were the same as when using the 'demean' option.
Could I get some insights on how the pvarfeols function handles fixed effects?

@jbowman answered this question here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/649270/how-does-the-pvarfeols-function-from-the-r-panelvar-package-handle-fixed-effects
